# T-SQL Self Join in combination with aggregate function

Tags: t-sql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tree](
 [AutoID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Category] [varchar](10) NULL,
 [Condition] [varchar](10) NULL,
 [Description] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Tree] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [AutoID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The data looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[Tree]
           ([Category]
           ,[Condition]
           ,[Description])
     VALUES ('1','Alpha','Type 1')
INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[Tree]
           ([Category]
           ,[Condition]
           ,[Description])
     VALUES ('1','Alpha','Type 1')
INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[Tree]
           ([Category]
           ,[Condition]
           ,[Description])
     VALUES ('2','Alpha','Type 2')
INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[Tree]
           ([Category]
           ,[Condition]
           ,[Description])
     VALUES ('2','Alpha','Type 2')
GO
```

I try now to do the following:

```
SELECT Category,COUNT(*) as CategoryCount FROM Tree where Condition = 'Alpha' group by Category
```

However, I also wish to get the Description for each Element. I tried several subqueries, self joins etc., but I always come to the problem that the subquery cannot return more than one record.

The problem is caused by a poor database design which I cannot change and I have run out of ideas as to how to get this done in a single query.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the result set should look like?  I'm a little confused by the need to also pull description.  It seems like you're trying to combine too many different things into a single query.

Comment: Category = 1, CategoryCount = 2, Description = Type 1;
Category = 2, CategoryCount = 2, Description = Type 2;

Comment: That sample result set does not seem to match up with the sample data you show above.  What is Offer 1 and Offer 3?

Comment: Sorry i updated the sample. The result should match now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need description, you have to include it in the aggregate

```
SELECT  Category ,
        [Description] ,
        COUNT(*) AS CategoryCount
FROM    Tree
WHERE   Condition = 'Alpha'
GROUP BY Category ,
        [Description]
```